# Error: event.findElement is not a function while trying to create slider for my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slider

I m new at ROR.
In my app I need slider and I found this article.

http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/01/art-of-reusing-code-in-your-web.html

But it is giving following error:

"event.findElement is not a function.
var element = event.findElement(this.selector); "

in prototype.js.
Can anybody tell me why this error is coming??

Answer (score 0):

I think that article is based on the javascript framework MooTools, and maybe you have not downloaded Mootools or you dont have it inside your Rails app. Download it from http://mootools.net/

Maybe searching for "Rails mootools tutorial" will give you some basics on this also so you can understand better what's going on.

Comment: i have installed mootools but on clicking next or previous links i am getting this error:

Comment: 1)
el is null
 handleEvent()
  event = click clientX=87, clientY=284
  bind()
 responder()
  event = click clientX=87, clientY=284
 var element = event.findElement(this.selector);

2)
event.findElement is not a function
var element = event.findElement(this.selector);